# iron-ajax ignores duplicate params

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

So I am using iron-ajax's params to send queries to my api; the params field of the ajax calls this function `params="ajaxParams"`. The problem i've ran into is that when I call `amount: ...` more than once the second one replaces it in the query.

```
 //enters praramaters into the iron-ajax params, this automatically
 // gets added onto the ajax link, and will generate a new request when a change happens.
        _getParams: function(searchQuery, amountMin, amountMax){
          return{
            name: searchQuery,
            amount: '>=' + amountMin,
            amount: '<=' + amountMax
          }
        },
```

This is what the encoded query string looks like in the xhr request:

`path/to/api/data?name=bob&amount=%3C%3D50000`

And the query for this was:

```
name: 'bob',
amount: '>=' + 5000,
amount: '<=' + 50000
```

Additionally Ive tried:

```
 return{
            name: searchQuery,
            amount: '>' + amountMin + '&amount<' + amountMax
          }
```

but the out put just gets encoded into:

`path/to/api/data?name=bob&amount=%3E5000%26amount%3C50000`

To summarise I am trying to get the following query from iron-ajax params, but it seems that the `params` argument wont accept having duplicate parameters:

`path/to/api/data?name=bob&amount=%3E5000&amount=%3E50000`

Edit:

as Gar pointed out this seems to be a js issue where 2 object properties are bieng returned, as a work around to this I tried to get rid of the params and just add the variables to the api url:

```
<iron-ajax  auto
                    url="path/to/api/data?name={{searchQuery}}
                    &amount=>={{amountMin}}
                    &amount=<={{amountMax}}"                       
                    handle-as="json" 
                    method="GET"></iron-ajax>
```

this will break the url into this though

`path/to/api/data?name=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&amount=%3E=5000%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&amount=%3C=50000`

Comment: This is a javascript issue, you are returning an "object", and you've set twice the same property.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the issue here.

Comment: a variable can only have 1 value, amount is either the first or the second value, could you rename them to amountLowbound/amountUpbound ?